# Modal Box Repeated 3 Times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on this page, and it's main idea to click one of these buttons
and it will open a popup modal box with a certain video
i'm trying this with the same video it's not a problem
but the problem that when you try to close the video it appears that there's 3 modal boxes opened so you have to close 3 times. my expectations that it will be one box to close not 3 of course.
I've tried to make every video a variable number on a href tag like this
`<button href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Marwan Moussa</button>`
`<button href="#1" class="cd-popup-trigger">Final Maro Trying</button>`
`<button href="#2" class="cd-popup-trigger">Marwaaaaan</button>`
But Not Working.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //open popup
    $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
    });

    //close popup
    $('.cd-popup').on('click', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
    //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.which == '27') {
            $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600');
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
main {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: "";
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

html * {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: #8f9cb5;
    background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
    color: #35a785;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */

.img-replace {
    /* replace text with an image */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    color: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-nugget-info {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.cd-nugget-info a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5e6e8d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.cd-nugget-info span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cd-nugget-info span svg {
    display: block;
}

.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
    fill: #5e6e8d;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5e6e8d;
    color: #fff;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 3em auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 50em;
    background: #35a785;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .cd-popup-trigger {
        margin: 6em auto;
    }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-popup {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}

.cd-popup.is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 4em auto;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.25em 0.25em 0.4em 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.cd-popup-container p {
    padding: 3em 1em;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    list-style: none;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
    background: #fc7169;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0.25em;
}

.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
    background-color: #fc8982;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a {
    background: #b6bece;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}

.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a:hover {
    background-color: #c5ccd8;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before,
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #8f9cb5;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: 8px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    right: 8px;
}

.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .cd-popup-container {
        margin: 8em auto;
    }
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #151E3F;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    >* {
        margin: 5px;
    }
}

.media {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.layer {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10px;
    height: 90%;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #151E3F;
}

p {
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
    transform: scale(0.1)
}

p {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.media:hover .layer {
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 90%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

p {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        transform: scale(0.6);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: block;
        >* {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>..</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Modal -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="http://laurefinch.beget.tech/fav.ico">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <h1>Lectures</h1>
        <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
            <!-- AJAX response must be wrapped in the modal's root class. -->
            <div class="modal">
                <p>Second AJAX Example!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="layer">
                    <button href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Marwan Moussa</button>
                    <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
                        <div class="cd-popup-container">
                            <video style="padding:30px;" width="320" height="240" controls>
                                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- cd-popup-container -->
                    </div>
                    <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">Sheraton</p>
                </div>
                <img src="/1st/upload/Marwan Moussa - Sheraton.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="layer">
                    <button href="#1" class="cd-popup-trigger">Final Maro Trying</button>
                    <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
                        <div class="cd-popup-container">
                            <video style="padding:30px;" width="320" height="240" controls>
                                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- cd-popup-container -->
                    </div>
                    <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">Sheraaaton</p>
                </div>
                <img src="/1st/upload/Finaal.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="layer">
                    <button href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Marwaaaaan</button>
                    <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
                        <div class="cd-popup-container">
                            <video style="padding:30px;" width="320" height="240" controls>
                                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- cd-popup-container -->
                    </div>
                    <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">ggggg</p>
                </div>
                <img src="/1st/upload/Marwan Moussa- Sheraton.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `.next()` in the example below it seems to solve your problem:

```
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
});
```

Also please note you have 2 x `<body>` tag in your document.

The problem was that you were adding the class `is-visible` to all `cd-popup` elements.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //open popup
  $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
  });

  //close popup
  $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  });
  //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == '27') {
      $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600');
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
main {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */

.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}

.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #fff;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}

.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25em 0.25em 0.4em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0.25em;
}

.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a {
  background: #b6bece;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}

.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a:hover {
  background-color: #c5ccd8;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before,
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}

.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #151E3F;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  >* {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

.media {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.layer {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10px;
  height: 90%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #151E3F;
}

p {
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  transform: scale(0.1)
}

p {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.media:hover .layer {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 90%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

p {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
    >* {
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>..</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="http://laurefinch.beget.tech/fav.ico">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <h1>Lectures</h1>

  <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <!-- AJAX response must be wrapped in the modal's root class. -->
    <div class="modal">
      <p>Second AJAX Example!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="layer">
        <button href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Marwan Moussa</button>

        <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
          <div class="cd-popup-container">
            <video style="padding:30px;" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
          </div>
          <!-- cd-popup-container -->
        </div>
        <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">Sheraton</p>
      </div>
      <img src="/1st/upload/Marwan Moussa - Sheraton.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="layer">
        <button href="#1" class="cd-popup-trigger">Final Maro Trying</button>

        <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
          <div class="cd-popup-container">
            <video style="padding:30px;" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
          </div>
          <!-- cd-popup-container -->
        </div>
        <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">Sheraaaton</p>
      </div>
      <img src="/1st/upload/Finaal.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="layer">
        <button href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Marwaaaaan</button>

        <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
          <div class="cd-popup-container">
            <video style="padding:30px;" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
          </div>
          <!-- cd-popup-container -->
        </div>
        <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">ggggg</p>
      </div>
      <img src="/1st/upload/Marwan Moussa- Sheraton.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```